# What is the Vision VBA equivalent to Access' Application object?

Tags: vba, ms-office, visio

In Access VBA, you can access properties/methods of the running application by typing the word **Application**, followed by a period, followed by what you want.

For example, I can instantiate and show a FileDialog like so:

```
Dim openFileDialogue As Object
Set openFileDialogue = Application.FileDialog(3)
openFileDialogue.Show
```

If I wanted to do this in Visio VBA, what would I need to substitute **Application** for in the above code?

Thanks

Comment: http://www.microsoftfaqs.com/Articles/1133187/FileDialog_Visio_2003_dilemma

Answer (score 1):

Try this link: http://visguy.com/vgforum/index.php?topic=738.0

At the very bottom is a code sample from "Nikolay" that shows an alternative way of getting the Fi
It shows an alternative (though more complex) way of getting the File Dialog to show up in Visio